# Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance

Tags: c#, arrays, split

Is someone able to help me out with the following please, I'm trying to split data from an input file (2 pieces of data per line, separated by either of the delimiters specified in the code below). To do this I have declared the string array 'split input', however when I run the program I get a runtime error [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YELRo.png) with the split input line inside the while loop highlighted in yellow. I can't see what I am doing wrong, I'm copying sample code which seems to be working fine :(
NB - the messageBox line below the yellow is just for my testing to prove the split worked

```
        private int DetermineArraySize(StreamReader inputFile)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            inputFile.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private void ReadIntoArray(StreamReader inputFile, string[] gameArray, int[] revArray)
    {
        string rawInput;
        string[] splitInput = new string[2];
        int count = 0;
        char[] delimiters = {'=', '@',};

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream || count < gameArray.Length)
        {
            rawInput = inputFile.ReadLine();
            {
                splitInput = rawInput.Split(delimiters);
                MessageBox.Show(splitInput[0] + " // " + splitInput[1]);

                count++;
            }

        }

    }

    private void rdGameSalesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("GameSales.txt");    //Open Input File
        int arraySize = DetermineArraySize(inputFile);              //Use input file to determine array size
        string[] gameTitle = new string[arraySize];                 //Declare array for GameTitle
        int[] revenue = new int[arraySize];                         ///Declare array for Revenue

        ReadIntoArray(inputFile, gameTitle, revenue);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use debug and see what is null in your code ! I suppose your count < gameArray.Length, but your file is in the end of the stream and rawInput is null.

Comment: The call to ReadLine returns null at least once before the EndOfStream.

Comment: why do you check `count < gameArray.Length`? count is always 0

Comment: I hadn't added 'count++ line' below the messagebox line as I wanted to see if the file was being read before I continued. I have added it now but I'm still getting same error. It doesn't look like the input file is being read. I have updated my original post with extra code so you can see where I am passing the input file to to the method as an argument

Answer (score 1):

Just add check on `null`.

ReadLine Method returns null if the end of the input stream is reached. It is possible because you check `!inputFile.EndOfStream` or `count < gameArray.Length`. So in the second condition has a possibility to get null when input filre reading

```
 while (!inputFile.EndOfStream || count < gameArray.Length)
        {
            rawInput = inputFile.ReadLine();
            if(rawInput !=null)
            {
              splitInput = rawInput.Split(delimiters);
              MessageBox.Show(splitInput[0] + " // " + splitInput[1]); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: That has worked to get rid of the error, but I don't understand why 'rawinput' is null, it should be reading from the text file I passed as an argument when calling the method?

Comment: Because you read file line by line and if it is the end of file it's still reading one more line because `count < gameArray.Length` is passed

Answer (score 0):

Check for null instead of end of stream.

```
 while((rawInput = Inputfile.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     splitInput = rawInput.Split(delimiters);
     MessageBox.Show(...);
 }
```

Comment: wouldn't it break the loop if an empty line is in between two non empty lines? In that case this won't be a proper solution!!